# Word Frequency Analysis - TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, word-frequency

I am running a code on Jupyter Notebook regarding Word Frequency Analysis using this website: http://theautomatic.net/2017/10/12/word-frequency-analysis/ ... As I get to the end of the process, I get an error when running that says the following:

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'.

Basically, I have to filter out articles that don't mention Netflix at least 3 times.

```
article_to_freq = {article:freq for article, freq in 
                   article_to_freq.items() if freq >= 3}
```

The error seem to happen on the 2nd line of this code: `article_to_freq.items() if freq >= 3}`

As mentioned before, I keep getting:

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Could you share with us your code?

Comment: It looks like `freq` is list and you can't compare list to int. Take a look what does `freq` actually contains. You can do this by (temporary) replacing `if freq >= 3` with `print(freq)` which will print content of every `freq`.

Comment: If it only contains one int (like `[4]`), you need to replace `if freq >= 3` with `if freq[0] >= 3`.

Comment: Please check this and update question with more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the problem would be that you are comparing "freq" which is a list(array) to 3 which is an integer(number). The solution is to use len(freq) which would compare the length of the array with the number 3 as showed in the example below:

```
#random example of the list
freq =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

#you use len() to get the length of the array
if len(freq) >= 3:
    print(freq) #or do what ever it is you want to do with it
```

Hope this helped